# CustomPage class deserialization is not working with fiegn client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, openfeign

I have custompage class as follows

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DashboardResponseModel<T> extends PageImpl<T> {

  private Integer count;
  private Integer totalCount;

  public DashboardResponseModel(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, Long total) {
    super(content, pageable, total);
  }

  public DashboardResponseModel(List<T> content) {
    super(content);
  }

  public DashboardResponseModel(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, Long total, Integer count,
      Integer totalCount) {
    super(content, pageable, total);
    this.count = count;
    this.totalCount = totalCount;
  }

  public DashboardResponseModel(List<T> content, Integer count, Integer totalCount) {
    super(content);
    this.count = count;
    this.totalCount = totalCount;
  }
```

Below is Fiegn configuration:

```
public class OKHTTPWithFeignClientConfiguration {
  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  private String appName;

  @Bean
  public Contract feignContract() {
    return new SpringMvcContract();
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestInterceptor requestStartInterceptor() {
    return new FeignRequestStartLoggerInterceptor();
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestInterceptor requestTrackerInterceptor() {
    return new FeignRequestTrackerInterceptor();
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestInterceptor userAgentInterceptor(@Autowired Client client) {
    return new FeignUserAgentInterceptor(appName, client.getClass().getPackageName());
  }

  @Bean
  public ResponseInterceptor requestEndInterceptor() {
    return new FeignRequestEndLoggerInterceptor();
  }

  @Bean
  public OkHttpClient client() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
  }

  @Bean
  public Encoder encoder() {
    return new JacksonEncoder(objectMapper());
  }

  @Bean
  public Decoder decoder() {
    return new JacksonDecoder(objectMapper());
  }

  private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new PageJacksonModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new SortJacksonModule());
    return objectMapper;
  }
```

I'm using Fiegn client to call other application and in response, I'm getting `DashboardResponseModel` but fiegn client is not able to deserialize the response.

Below is the error:

> Failed to narrow type [simple type, class com.abc.xyz.dashboard.model.DashboardResponseModel<com.abc.xyz.dashboard.model.EmployeeMissingInformationModel>] with annotation (value org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.PageJacksonModule$SimplePageImpl), from 'com.abc.xxyz.dashboard.model.DashboardResponseModel': Class `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.PageJacksonModule$SimplePageImpl` not subtype of `com.abc.xyz.dashboard.model.DashboardResponseModel<com.abc.xyz.dashboard.model.EmployeeMissingInformationModel>` reading PUT http://127.0.0.1:8312/v1.0/customer/32/registered-entity/7437/dashboard/missing-information/details?size=6&page=0

**Is there any additional configuration needed for DashboardResponseModel to deserialize?**